# Получить последний ИД  одной таблицы и вписать его в столбец другой таблицы

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных, jdbc

Здравствуйте.

Помогите, пожалуйста, в таком вопросе. Есть таблица WORD и таблица TRANSLATION. Их поля:

```
WORD(ID_WORD(primary),WORD) TRANSLATION(ID_TRANSLATION(primary),TRANSLATION,ID_WORD(foreign))
```

Я хочу сперва ввести слово в WORD, а потом копирнуть его ид в таблицу TRANSLATION, но не получается. Подскажите, что делать?

```
dbConnection = DbManager.getDBConnection();
statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
word = "INSERT INTO WORD (WORD) VALUES ('"+s[0]+"'); "
            +"SET @last_id_in_table1 =  LAST_INSERT_ID(); "
            +"INSERT INTO TRANSLATION (ID_WORD,TRANSLATION) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'"+s[1]+"');";
statement.execute(word);
```

Если что, ошибка вылетает такая: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near  ...`
УПД: Если задать запрос в mysql workbench, то он работает! Но из java нет(

Comment: Тут были? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797794/multiple-queries-executed-in-java-in-single-statement